# Showing a UIActionSheet from a UIBarButtonItem trouble

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet

So I set up my storyboard files and whatnot and made an action for my UIBarButton. In this method I create an action sheet and display it. But it seems no matter what I do it always displays from the bottom. Can't you get it to pop down from the navbar with a little arrow in the border that points to the button you clicked? Well, I'm having trouble finding the right method. Here's what I have tried:

```
- (IBAction)actionBtnPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Options" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Report User" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
    [actionSheet showFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES];
}
```

I have also tried

```
[actionSheet showFromToolbar:self.navigationController.toolbar];
```

instead of showFromBarButtonItem, but these methods aren't reading my mind that I want it to display from the button. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this for iPhone or iPad?

Comment: iPhone, does this not work for iPhone?

Comment: No, it shows as a popover with the arrow in iPad only.

Comment: Well now I feel dumb. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an iPhone, actionsheet is always displayed from bottom of the screen. What you meant is a `UIPopover` which is available only for an iPad. However, you can use a custom popover if you want to use the same feature in your app. Check [WEPopover](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover). It allows you to create pop over in iPhone and it can be safely used to draw popover in your app. You can show the required items inside this popover.

Comment: I wish I would have knew about this earlier. I created my own little popover which works alright, but I spent way too much time doing it.